# broadcast receiver for sms receive is geting call at missied call in Android

Tags: android

I have created auto text reply application in which i declared receiver in manifeast file and declared action tag as follows.

```
<receiver android:name=".SmsReceiver"> 
          <intent-filter> 
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
          </intent-filter> </receiver>
```

In receiver class i just check action type of receiver as follows.

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
{

          if(intent.getAction().equalsIgnoreCase("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"))
         {
           Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();        
           SmsMessage[] msgs = null;
           String str = "";    
           if (bundle != null)
            {
             //---retrieve the SMS message received---
              Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
              msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
              for (int i=0; i<msgs.length; i++)
                 {
                    msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);                
                    str += "SMS from " + msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();                     
                    str += " :";
                    str += msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString();
                    str += "\n"; 
                    address=msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();
                 }
       /* other functionality........... */
     }

     }
```

Now this receiver is getting call for incoming text message but some time missed call also
i don't want this to get call on missed call. what i have to do to avoid missed call.

Thank You.
  Vikram

Answer (score 0):

see you can do it in this way: register a broadcaster for intent `android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED`

```
   registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver(){
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
            // do ur stuff;

        }
    }, new IntentFilter("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"));
```

u have to import this package first

```
   import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
```